# How can I find rows in Excel that have matching cells in the same rows as well as cells in these rows that do not match each other?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have a list of peoples' addresses, names, and genders and I want to find the heterosexual couples that live together. Each person represents a row in Excel. I first want to find people whose addresses match each other. Then I need to filter by male and female "rows" with the same addresses.

I can filter for duplicates, and get the matching addresses lined up, but how can I perform the second goal of matching only different-gender couples? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

insert a column named `id` and a column named `id_match`, like the image. put this formula in `E2` and fill down formula to all cells:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:A1;MATCH(A2;$E$1:E1;0));IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11;MATCH(1;INDEX(($A$2:$A$11<>A2)*($C$2:$C$11<>C2)*($D$2:$D$11=D2);0;1);0));"match not found"))`

also you can set this formula in cell `F2` to find match name:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$11;MATCH(E2;$A$2:$A$11;0));"")`

[image]